# How do I create a new webpage from a user submitted database entry?

Tags: php, mysql, html

I'm creating a dictionary database using php and MySQL. The user can search for a name, if it's there it brings up a list of matching links (eg: http://mydictionary/name.php) and then the user can click on said link and they are transported to a webpage that get's its information from the database. If there is no entry for the name in the database then the user is invited to make their own entry. I can get this to work using a html input form and then the php file to save it into the database.

The problem I have is that when this newly entered name is searched for, the link won't be active as it leads to a non-existent page. Can I get php to create the new url for me? Or does anyone know a way around this problem?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is create an .htaccess file and mod_rewrite.

This post will help you get started.

http://www.desiquintans.com/cleanurls

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly you can do it with mod_rewrite so you can hide your `name` parameter, for example:

```
http://example.com/result.php?name=user-given name
```

maps to

```
http://example.com/user-given-name.php
```

Answer (score 0):

If the others are right about what you want, this should do what you need:

.htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\.php$ nameLookup.php?name=$1
```

This will rewrite all URLs like this `myname.php`, `SomeName.php`, `name3.php` to URLs like `nameLookup.php?name=myname`, `nameLookup.php?name=SomeName` amd `nameLookup.php?name=name3`

You will need `mod_rewrite` enabled on your apache server. You can test this by creating a PHP file with this inside:

`<?php phpinfo(); ?>`

Check to see if the `mod_rewrite` module is enabled.