# how to create a new page when someone adds a database entry?

Tags: php, mysql, html

[How do I create a new webpage from a user submitted database entry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255929/how-do-i-create-a-new-webpage-from-a-user-submitted-database-entry)

I've read this question but have not quite understood it yet. Maybe someone can offer a little help?

Basically, I have a frame that has the main menu and the links to the side. As for refreshing the links to the side, I already know but to have a page newly added when a database entry is added is what still confuses the heck out of me.

Is there any other way to explain this a little clearly for me?

Comment: I don't understand the question. What do you mean by creating a new page? An actual HTML file on the server? Or do you just want to have a php page serve new content from the database?

Comment: Let's say that there are 4 links in the links page. When a new entry in the database is added, the links page will refresh and a new link will be added, therefore adding one link, making it 5 links in the link page.

Comment: I suggest you goto a basic tutorial site. Answering this would be subjective and would require more then a simple answer

Comment: And yes, it has to be a php page.

Comment: This question is very broad, you should probably go through some simple php+database tutorial.

Comment: I actually do know how to do the php+database stuff, its just this has gotten me really stumped.

Comment: Yes, kind of. It's been bugging me this whole week.

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to PHP, then there are frameworks that can help you do that.

Yii is a framework that can generate CRUD (Create Read Update Delete) pages from a database structure that you have.

Watch the screencasts here:

http://www.yiiframework.com/screencasts/